# Confusion about Lebesgue-Null set

Tags: measure-theory

> For $0 < k <n$ is $\;\mathbb{R}^{n-k}\times \{0\}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a Lebesgue null set.

For the case $n=2, k=1$ we have $$\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2.$$

I have problems understanding why the measure of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$, although $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\} = (x,0) \simeq \mathbb{R}$ is a null set.

Answer (score 0):

Given any $\epsilon > 0,$ can you cover $[a,b] \times \{0\}$ with countably many regions (you don't say whether your coverings have to be rectangular regions or circular disks or something else) having total area less than $\epsilon$? (This can be done with one rectangular region if you get to use rectangles.) This shows  $[a,b] \times \{0\}$ has Lebesgue $2$-measure zero. Now use the fact that a countable union of Lebesgue $2$-measure sets has Lebesgue $2$-measure.

Comment: I do not know the term Lebesgue $k$-measure. What does it exactly mean? What is the difference between a Lebesgue $1$-measure and a Lebesgue $2$- or $k$-measure?

Comment: The numbers $1,$ $2,$ $k$ signify which space --- ${\mathbb R}^{1},$ ${\mathbb R}^{2},$ ${\mathbb R}^{k}$ --- Lebesgue measure is being is being used in.

Comment: So, the property "null set" is depending on the underlying space? Does that mean, that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a null set in $\mathbb{R}$ but compared to the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is?

Comment: Yes, it is very dependent on the underlying space, and this is what one would expect. For example, a line takes up very little of ${\mathbb R}^{2},$ so little that I would think most people would say a line has zero area if they had to pick an area to assign the line. Think about throwing a dart at a dartboard. The probability is $0$ that you'll land on a specified line segment (a true mathematical line segment that has $0$ width). BTW, my sporadicity in these comments is because I'm at work (non-academic) and I can only drop by at various irregular times, usually for short moments.

Comment: I accept every help I can get, so I am thankfull even for your sporadic comments and answers.